# expo react-native react-navigation react-intl how to trigger an update to the messages once the user locale is resolved

Tags: redux, react-navigation, expo, react-intl

I am using expo, react-native, redux, react-navigation, and react-intl. Expo has this async `Localization.getCurrentLocaleAsync()` function to retrieve the locale asynchronously. I encountered problem propagating changes of locale and messages down to child components. 
For example, if I set initial locale to "es" in "Root.js", when the `Localization.getCurrentLocaleAsync()` kick in and set the locale to "en", the updated messages was not reflected in the child component "Login.js". As such, the simulator throws a console.error: `Missing message: "Login.login" for locale: "es", using default message as fallback` while I updated the locale and message in the `root.js` state Here's my code:
`root.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { DangerZone } from 'expo';
import { IntlProvider, addLocaleData, injectIntl } from 'react-intl';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import AuthLoadingPage from './containers/authLoading';
import LoginPage from './containers/login';
import SignupPage from './containers/signup';
import HomePage from './containers/home';
import NotFoundPage from './containers/notFound';
import configureStore from './configureStore';
import en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';
import es from 'react-intl/locale-data/es';
import localeData from './build/data.json';
addLocaleData([...en, ...es]);

const { Localization } = DangerZone;

const { persistor, store } = configureStore();

const AuthTab = createBottomTabNavigator({
    login: { screen: LoginPage },
    signup: { screen: SignupPage },
},{ 
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarVisible: false,
  },
  lazyLoad: true,
});

const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  authLoading: AuthLoadingPage,
  main: { screen: HomePage},
  auth: AuthTab,
},{
  initialRouteName: 'authLoading',
});

class Root extends React.Component {
  constructor(p) {
    super(p);
    this.state = { 
      currentLocale: 'es',
      messages: localeData['es'],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Localization.getCurrentLocaleAsync()
      .then(currentLocale => {
        console.log("currentLocale is >>>", currentLocale);
        this.setState({
          currentLocale,
          messages: localeData[currentLocale],
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    console.log("this.state.message???", this.state.messages);
    return (
      <IntlProvider
        locale={this.state.currentLocale}
        key={this.state.currentLocale}
        messages={this.state.messages}
        textComponent={Text}
      >
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate
            loading={<NotFoundPage />}
            onBeforeLift={() => {}}
            persistor={persistor}
          >
            <MainNavigator />
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </IntlProvider>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default Root;
```

and "containers/Login.js":

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { injectIntl, intlShape, FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import { FormLabel, FormInput } from 'react-native-elements';

import { authenticate } from '../modules/auth/actions';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

class LoginPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.props.dispatch(authenticate(email, password))
    .then(() => {
      navigation.navigate('main');
    })
  }

  gotoSignup(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.navigate('signup');
  }

  render() {
    const { isAuthenticated, navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.loginLogo}>
          <FormattedMessage
            id={ 'Login.login' }
            defaultMessage={ 'Welcome to login screen!' }
          />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,

  },
  loginLogo: {
    flex:1,
  },
  loginForm: {
    flex: 2,
  },
  loginFormContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255, 0.8)',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  buttoncontainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#23618C',
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingVertical: 15,
  },
  buttontext: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#fff',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { auth } = state;
  const { loading, isAuthenticated } = auth;
  return {
    loading,
    isAuthenticated
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginPage);
```

you can also find the relavent code in github: 
root.js:  https://github.com/7seven7lst/mobile-client-new/blob/master/root.js
containers/Login.js: https://github.com/7seven7lst/mobile-client-new/blob/master/containers/login.js

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. the above should be working. I got this id messed up. it should be "Login.Login" because that's what I have in the `data.json` file.

```
<FormattedMessage
   id={ 'Login.login' }
   defaultMessage={ 'Welcome to login screen!' }
/>
```